# Having Issues with a recursive function (Python)

Tags: python, function, recursion, while-loop, tweepy

Hello this is for my into to computer science final, using python and Tweepy. The function works until the while loop, where the input automatically goes to the else statement. I don't understand why this is happening, but I am assuming that it has to do with comparing the question variable with the string 'yes'

```
#Search for a user
def usersearch():
    fp=open('UserSearch.txt','w')
    user_search=input("Please enter the name of the user you would like to look up")
    user = api.get_user(user_search)
    fp.write(user_search)
    fp.write("\n")
    fp.write("User details:")
    fp.write("\n")
    print("User details:")
    print("User name:" + " " + user.name)
    fp.write("User name:" + " " + user.name)
    fp.write("\n")
    print("User description:" + " " + user.description)
    fp.write("User description:" + " " + user.description)
    fp.write("\n")
    print("User location:" + " " + user.location)
    fp.write("User location:" + " " + user.location)
    fp.write("\n")
#Issue recalling function    
    while True:
        question = input("Would you like to look up another user? (yes/no)").lower
        if question == 'yes':
            usersearch()
            continue
        elif question == 'no':
            break
        else:
            print('Please enter either (yes/no)')
```

Comment: in your line `question = input("Would you like to look up another user? (yes/no)").lower`, you forgot to put `()` in front of lower. it must be like `question = input("Would you like to look up another user? (yes/no)").lower()`

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you so much.